# Find smallest possible value of $N$ such that, any $N$ consecutive positive integers, has at least one of them coprime to $374$ .

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $N$ be a number such that whenever you take $N$ consecutive positive integers, at least one of them is coprime to $374$ . What is the smallest possible value of $N$ ?

My Attempt:

I started by doing a prime factorization of $374.$ We have, $374=2.11.17$, and we may say, that for a number say, $n$ to be coprime with $N$ it, must not be divisible by either of the primes $\{2,11,17\}$ . This means, if we take, $n\pmod n$ then the remainder is $\neq 2,11$ or $17.$ Then, let's say we pick   a number and find it has a remainder of $1$ then we are done. If this is not the case, then, let's say the number we chose leaves a temainder of $2,$ $11$ or $17$ then, if we take the next consecutive number, it will have a remainder of $3,$  $12$ or $18$ (respectively) depending upon the case. If the number we chose is leaves a remainder of $2$ then, choosing $2$ consecutive numbers is enough. If this is not the case, then we have two cases. Either the number chosen has a remainder $11$ or $17$. If this is the former case, i.e the number leaves a remainder of $11$ then, picking the next number we have a remainder $12$ and again the next number leaves a remainder of $13$ and then, we see, we have to pick three consecutive numbers. If this is the later case, i.e we have a remainder of $17$, then, we have choose $3$ numbers again (similarly).

But then I realised we, need to take care of the cases, where the number leaves a remainder which is even and also the cases where the remainders are either divisible by $11$ or $17.$ But there are $214$ numbers (by PIE) which are divisible by either $2,11$ or $17.$ We can't go on repeating the same process above for each of the $214$ remainders, that are not coprime with $374.$ Is there any alternative way to find the answer?

Comment: You might look for example at the integers starting at $118$ and see what happens

Comment: @Henry Isn't that also a huge process ?

Comment: In any six consecutive numbers, how many can be multiples of $2$? of $11$? of $17$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson In any six consecutive nos.  there are (at most $3$  multiples and least $2$ multiples of $2$), (at most $1$  multiple and least $0$ multiple of $11$), (at most $1$  multiple and least $0$ multiple of $17$)

Comment: With my suggestion $118,120,122$ are multiples of $2$, $119$ is a multiple of $17$, and $121$ is a multiple of $11$, so five is not the answer.  but $6>3+1+1$

Comment: @Henry But then how did you know that things will become so smooth on checking $\gt 118$ ? Please share the motivation behind this?

Comment: Your reply to @GerryMyerson shows you do not need more than six, since $6>3+1+1$.  My example shows you do need more than five, since none of $118,119,120,121,122$ are coprime to $374$ (it is motivated by finding odd multiples of $11$ and $17$ separated by $2$)